# How do i add a fading border to my nav bar CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a line above and below my `nav-bar` that would fade out at the ends of it, like shown in the image below:
[image]

this is my HTML so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Portfolio - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <img class="circle" title="circle" alt="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
            <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
            <img class="circle" title="circle" alt="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="webInfo">
            <p>Hi, my name is Alex Trotter and this is my portfolio website</p>
            <p>below you will find some of work that I have created.</p>
            <p>Above you can navigate to different pages to learn more about me.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="exampleWork1"></div>
        <div id="exampleWork2"></div>
        <div id="exampleWork3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
}
#header {
background-color: #b9fee2;
width: 1920px;
height: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a {
text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:visited {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
} 
#nav li {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
#nav a {
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
#nav a:link {
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
font-size: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
#nav a:visited {
color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
font-size: 30px;
}
.circle {
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Whenever I try to add a border to the nav-bar it goes across the entire screen, but if I make it so that the nav-bar border is only as big as it needs to be, the nav bar isn't in the center of the screen. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use ::before and ::after, and apply CSS gradients for the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of positioned pseudo-elements with a linear gradient background would be probably the simplest method.

*Note:  Your menu HTML is invalid, `ul` can only have `li` as direct children..not images, you can search SO for other options for menu dividers.*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #b9fee2;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#nav::before,
#nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
#nav::before {
  top: 0;
}
#nav:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#nav a {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
#nav a:link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#nav a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the CSS, add a `hover`:

```
#nav {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
#nav.noHighlight {
   background:transparent;
   border-color:transparent;
}
```

then add a jQuery script, and put

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#abc').fadeIn();
    $('#abc').addClass('noHighlight');
},1000);
```